# Different execution times of parallelized sync and async methods depending on the number of available threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, async-await, threadpool

I wrote a small test of different execution times of parallelized synchronous asynchronous functions depending on the number of available threads, and a lot of related questions appeared, please help me figure it out.

Results with default threads settings:
[image: Results with default thread settings]

Results with the addition of these settings: `<ThreadPoolMinThreads>1000</ThreadPoolMinThreads>` и `<ThreadPoolMaxThreads>1000</ThreadPoolMaxThreads>`.
[image]

1. Why, when I put a fixed number of 1000 threads, asynchronous operations began to degrade?
2. Why are the results of `GetSyncExecutionTimeThread` and `GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay` different? `GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay` is executed asynchronously and why does this happen without await?
3. Why is `GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay` faster than `GetAsyncExecutionTimeInTasks`? `GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay` is executed asynchronously and why does this happen without await?
4. What is the difference between `GetAsyncExecutionTime` and `GetAsyncExecutionTimeInTasks`? As far as I understand, `GetAsyncExecutionTime` is the choice of the number of processing threads at the discretion of the `Task`?
5. Why running the application with these methods separately shows the best results of each separately? Subsequent method calls are worse than if I run them separately, why?

Thanks for the help!

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var upperLimitsOfRanges = new List<int>() { 100, 1000, 5000, 15000 };

var millisecondsTimeout = 100;

foreach (var upperLimitOfRange in upperLimitsOfRanges)
{
    var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, upperLimitOfRange);

    var syncExecutionTimeThread = await GetSyncExecutionTimeThread(collection, millisecondsTimeout);

    var syncExecutionTimeDelay = await GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay(collection, millisecondsTimeout);

    var asyncExecutionTime = await GetAsyncExecutionTime(collection, millisecondsTimeout);

    var asyncExecutionTimeInTasks = await GetAsyncExecutionTimeInTasks(collection, millisecondsTimeout);

    Console.WriteLine($"Iterations: {upperLimitOfRange}; " +
        $"Sync thread: {syncExecutionTimeThread} ms; " +
        $"Sync delay: {syncExecutionTimeDelay} ms; " +
        $"Async: {asyncExecutionTime} ms; " +
        $"Async in tasks: {asyncExecutionTimeInTasks} ms");
}

Console.Read();

async Task<long> GetSyncExecutionTimeThread(IEnumerable<int> collection, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var executionTimeWithoutAsync = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(_ => Task.Run(() => Delay(millisecondsTimeout))));

    executionTimeWithoutAsync.Stop();

    return executionTimeWithoutAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

async Task<long> GetSyncExecutionTimeDelay(IEnumerable<int> collection, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var executionTimeWithoutAsync = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(_ => Task.Run(() => DelayAsync(millisecondsTimeout))));

    executionTimeWithoutAsync.Stop();

    return executionTimeWithoutAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

async Task<long> GetAsyncExecutionTime(IEnumerable<int> collection, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var executionTimeWithAsync = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(async _ => await DelayAsync(millisecondsTimeout).ConfigureAwait(false)));

    executionTimeWithAsync.Stop();

    return executionTimeWithAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

async Task<long> GetAsyncExecutionTimeInTasks(IEnumerable<int> collection, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var executionTimeWithAsync = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(_ => Task.Run(async () => await DelayAsync(millisecondsTimeout).ConfigureAwait(false))));

    executionTimeWithAsync.Stop();

    return executionTimeWithAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

bool Delay(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
    return true;
}

async Task<bool> DelayAsync(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    await Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You do know that every threads that is created uses 1MB of RAM? 1,000 threads is around 1GB of RAM just to support the threads. That takes time to spin up.

Comment: @Enigmativity Are they not created when the application is launched with this setting? In any case, the synchronous call is executed first, and with 1000 threads it runs faster, and asynchronous ones get worse because of this.

Comment: Better use benchmark dotnet if you want the numbers to be more than a very coarse hint.

Comment: @WebFR - The `ThreadPool` threads are created on-demand, not at start-up.

Comment: Your measurements are wrong. Use benchmark dotnet. All other ways to get reliable numbers are wrong.

Comment: Did you run your program in release mode as standalone program, or in debug mode with the VS debugger attached? What .NET platform did you targeted? .NET 7? .NET Framework?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I started it in debugging mode with the VS debugger connected. .NET 7.

Comment: In that case you've learned about the performance of the VS debugger instead of the performance of your program. Try running your program without the debugger attached, and you might see a completely different picture. Unless you run routinely your finished programs with the debugger attached (I have a friend that does that), you should do your benchmarks in release mode without the debugger.

Comment: Also, please use Benchmark.Net for any timing measurement. Or else you'll learn about how not to do timing measurements instead of the performance of your program. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer to the question about the threadpool (very interesting, though). But here are answers to 2-4.

Question 2: `Task.Delay` returns control. `Thread.Sleep`, on the other hand, blocks so you don't get to spool a new `Delay` until the old one is finished. As Theodor Zoulias just educated me, `Task.Run` understands async delegates and returns the appropriate `Task` object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) which is why it 'operates asynchronously' without `await`.

Question 3: There is overhead in awaiting an async method. I am not sure of the exact details of the implementation in .NET, but somehow a callback is registered on the stack (or something along those lines). This accounts for the longer processing time.

Question 4: In `GetAsyncExecutionTimeInTasks` you call `Task.Run` which starts a new thread. In `GetAsyncExecutionTime` you simply kick off the async method on the same thread and await it. Calling `Task.Run` does exactly the same thing, but it kicks it off on a new thread, so you need to spool a new thread before the async call---which takes longer.

Comment: *"It doesn't make any sense, in practice, to call an async method without await."* -- Sure, but how is this relevant to the question(s) asked? Nowhere in the OP's code is the `DelayAsync` called in a fire-and-forget fashion. It may seem so in the fragment `Task.Run(() => DelayAsync`, but actually the `Task.Run` understands async delegates, and returns a `Task` that represents their asynchronous completion.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Ah, yes, I see that now. I didn't realize that!